# How to get all the columns from id and filter to specific column? odoo9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am getting the id of a customer by

```
customer = context.get('partner_id')
print customer

#output
#6
```

Now i want to fetch all the values of all columns from `res.partner` where `id == 6`

This will will give me many a recordset i guess

How do i filter the recordset so i can get the value which i want to work with.

Or if it is possible can i get the specific columns value not all. (that would be great)

If possible tell me how to do it in `old_api` and `new_api`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Old api**

```
self.pool.get('res.partner').search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', customer)])
```

This would return a list of id's that matched the search so you have to call `browse` to actually get the records

**New api**

```
self.env['res.partner'].search([('id', '=', customer)])
```

to get only a specific column, instead of all columns use the `search_read` method it's very similar to search only that it takes a second argument which is a list of the attributes you're interested in and it returns a list of dictionaries instead of a record sets. so let's say we're only interested in the column `value`

```
self.env['res.partner'].search_read([('id', '=', customer)], ['value'])
```

your result should look like this

```
[{'id': 1, 'value': 'some value'}, ...]
```

Comment: is there any way i can do `.search_read` in the old api. Or i can do it in `browse` itself. I am doing `c_item = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, customer, context=None)` and i am getting `res.partner(6,)`

Comment: No you can't search read was introduced in the new api with odoo 8, the best you can do is `c_item = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, customer, context=None).value`

Comment: Worked, Thank you :)